# Listview IsEnabled property not working in .Net maui

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

Listview IsEnabled property not working in .Net Maui. Please look into the below code.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,*">
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Switch Grid.Column="1" IsToggled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="Button1"  Clicked="Button_Clicked1"/>
        <Button Text="Button2" Clicked="Button_Clicked2"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{   
    //static public FoodViewModel Foods;
    public MainPage()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
        //Foods = new FoodViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = new FoodViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

In the upper code the Switch should be Enabled when listview enabled but im unable to toggle the switch.

Comment: A switch in the template will not be affected by the value of the ListViews IsEnabled property.  You need to set the enabled property in the model that the ListView is bound to

Comment: @neha May I know on which platform you are executing the code? Are you running it on `Windows` or the other platform?

Comment: im running on Android

Comment: Could you please provide the viewmodel code: `FoodViewModel`  in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.BindingContext = this;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Enabled property.

```
listView.Enabled = true;
```